# ¿Como buscar datos claves dentro de un bloque(inicio: [, fin: ])?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy haciendo una base de dato donde todos los datos están dentro de `[ ]`, pero todo lo que este afuera del bloque(`[]`) me gustaría que se ignorara.

```python
Comment.
[
    CI=3.234.535
    Nombre=Jhon
    Edad=50
]
CI=Si.sale.es.un.error
CI=1023122 Si sale tambien es un error.
[
    CI=33.744.800
    Nombre=Doe
    Edad=17
]
```

Lo de arriba es mi base de dato.
Mi intento fue: `/\[*CI=(\d|\.)*\]/gs`, con ayuda pude hacer algo que cumple con lo que deseo: `/\[.+(CI=(\d|\.)+).*\]/gs`. Pero ahora solo me retorna la última cedula ignorando la del primer bloque.

> ¿Como puedo hacer para que tome todos los datos que deseo dentro del bloque?
> o ¿Como puedo hacer para que tome todas las cedula que están dentro de los bloques?

```js
//Generado por https://regex101.com/r/3L3Iwe/1
const regex = /\[.+(CI=(\d|\.)+).*\]/gs;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('\\[.+(CI=(\\d|\\.)+).*\\]', 'gs')

const str = `[
    Nombre=Daniel
    Edad=0
    CI=20.321.234
]
CI=01020301
[
    Nombre=Alexander
    Edad=1
    CI=20.987.432
]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Buen día. Los `CI=...` que están fuera de los `[]`, ¿Siempre serán números sin los puntos o también pueden llevar puntos? o sea así => `20.321.234`.

Comment: Lo que este afuera del los corchetes los usare para comentarios, como dejarle nota a quien vea esa base de datos, etc... Los CI pueden ser representado sin punto o con puntos para representar las unidades. Solo que lo mas comun para las personas es escribirlos con puntos. @Cris223511.dev  . En otra palabras una cedula con 20321234 es lo mismo que 20.321.234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El **Greedy quantifier** (`*`) selecciona todos los caracteres posibles. Por este motivo ves que el primer `.*` selecciona el primer bloque.

En su lugar puedes utilizar el **Lazy quantifier** (`*?`) que selecciona la menor cantidad posible. Con el obtienes el efecto esperado.

Además, la expresión `(\d|\.)` genera un grupo extra porque está entre paréntesis. Puedes expresarlo como el conjunto `[\d.]` para deshacerte de él.

```js
const regex = /\[.*?(CI=[\d.]+).*?\]/gs

const str = `[
    Nombre=Daniel
    Edad=0
    CI=20.321.234
]
CI=01020301
[
    Nombre=Alexander
    Edad=1
    CI=20.987.432
]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar 2 expresiones regulares, una para encontrar todo el texto que esté dentro de los `[]`:

```js
const cadena = `[ Nombre=Daniel Edad=0 CI=20.321.234 ] CI=1023122 [ Nombre=Alexander Edad=1 CI=20.987.432 ]`;
const regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
const result = cadena.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Y de la cadena encontrada, volver a hacer otra búsqueda para encontrar los números siguientes de `CI=...`:

```js
const cadena = `[ Nombre=Daniel Edad=0 CI=20.321.234 ] CI=20.321.234 [ Nombre=Alexander Edad=1 CI=20.987.432 ]`;
const regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
const result = cadena.match(regex);
const numerosCI = result.map(match => match.match(/(?<=CI=)[\d.]+/g)[0]);
console.log(numerosCI);
```

En donde `(?<=CI=)` se le conoce como [**positive lookahead**](https://es.javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#resumen), quien se encarga de coincidir con el contenido después de `CI=`. Y luego de esto colocamos `[\d.]+` para asegurarse de encontrar una secuencia de dígitos o puntos.

---

Un ejemplo para ambos casos:

```js
const cadena1 = `[ Nombre=Daniel Edad=0 CI=20.321.234 ] CI=20.321.234 [ Nombre=Alexander Edad=1 CI=20.987.432 ]`;
const cadena2 = `[ Nombre=Daniel Edad=0 CI=20.321.234 ] CI=01020301 [ Nombre=Alexander Edad=1 CI=20.987.432 ]`;

const regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

const result1 = cadena1.match(regex);
const result2 = cadena2.match(regex);

const numerosCI1 = result1.map(match => match.match(/(?<=CI=)[\d.]+/g)[0]);
const numerosCI2 = result2.map(match => match.match(/(?<=CI=)[\d.]+/g)[0]);

console.log(numerosCI1);
console.log(numerosCI2);
```